# Aligning 8-bit Integer Array for Message Passing that Requires Long Alignment

Tags: c, arrays, memory-alignment, message-passing, numa

I am currently using OpenMP on a processor with a NUMA architecture and using the User Dynamic Network (UDN) that the board provides to route packets from each thread to the master thread. The overall idea of the program is simple: parallelize the subtraction of two 8-bit integer arrays element-wise and store the results into an array (C[i] = A[i] - B[i]).

Due to the NUMA architecture of the processor I'm using, allocating the arrays and then putting a simple OpenMP for loop pragma results in very poor performance. One of the ways I have achieved better performance is to instead allocate arrays of equal size as private arrays to each thread, and have each thread just work on its private data that was allocated by that thread. The idea is to have each thread work on local to get around the overhead of fetching data from other cores.

While this results in a performance increase, I am trying to accumulate the data from each thread into one final thread that can be used by the main program outside of the parallel region. However, when using the UDN to pass messages around, one of the requirements according the data sheet is that the buffer being sent and the buffer used to receive the data must be long-aligned.

Here is the code I have:

```
int size = 6000;
int threads = 20;

if(tmc_udn_init(NULL) != 0)
{
  printf("tmc_udn_init failure\n");
}

alloc_attr_t attrCfinal = ALLOC_INIT;
mspace mspCfinal = create_mspace_with_attr(0,0,&attrCfinal);
uint8_t *C_final = mspace_malloc(mspCfinal, sizeof(uint8_t)*(size*size));

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads)
{
  int j;

  int id = omp_get_thread_num();
  if(tmc_cpus_set_my_cpu(id) < 0)
  {
    printf("tmc_cpus_set_my_cpu failure, thread = %d\n", id);
  }

  if(tmc_udn_activate() < 0)
  {
    printf("tmc_udn_activate() failure, threads = %d\n", id);
  }

  #pragma omp barrier

  alloc_attr_t attrA = ALLOC_INIT;
  alloc_attr_t attrB = ALLOC_INIT;
  alloc_attr_t attrC = ALLOC_INIT;

  alloc_set_home(&attrA, ALLOC_HOME_HERE);
  alloc_set_home(&attrB, ALLOC_HOME_HERE);
  alloc_set_home(&attrC, ALLOC_HOME_HERE);

  mspace mspA = create_mspace_with_attr(0,0,&attrA);
  mspace mspB = create_mspace_with_attr(0,0,&attrB);
  mspace mspC = create_mspace_with_attr(0,0,&attrC);

  uint8_t *A_priv = mspace_malloc(mspA, sizeof(uint8_t)*((size*size)/threads));
  uint8_t *B_priv = mspace_malloc(mspB, sizeof(uint8_t)*((size*size)/threads));
  uint8_t *C_priv = mspace_malloc(mspC, sizeof(uint8_t)*((size*size)/threads));

  for(j=0; j<((size*size)/threads); j++)
  {
    A_priv[j] = 100;
    B_priv[j] = omp_get_thread_num();
    C_priv[j] = 0;
  }

  for(j=0; j<((size*size)/threads); j++)
  {
    C_priv[j] = A_priv[j] - B_priv[j];
  }

  if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
  {
    int k = 0;
    int h = 0;

    for(k=1; k<threads; k++)
    {
      int thread_num = tmc_udn1_receive();

      for(h=0; h<((size*size)/threads)/100; h++)
      {
        tmc_udn0_receive_buffer(&C_final[((thread_num-1)*((size*size)/threads))+(h*100)], 100);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    #pragma omp critical
    {
      DynamicHeader dest = tmc_udn_header_from_cpu(0);
      tmc_udn_send_1(dest, UDN1_DEMUX_TAG, omp_get_thread_num());

      int p = 0;
      for(p=0; p<((size*size)/threads)/100; p++)
      {
        tmc_udn_send_buffer(dest, UDN0_DEMUX_TAG, &C_priv[p*100], 100);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some notes about my code that might make it easier to look at:

- The send/receive buffer only allows up to 126 words at a time, so I am doing 100 for now just to make everything easily divisible when sending chunks of each array at a time.
- I know in my message passing/receiving that I am not including thread 0, this is something I am going to fix later after I figure this issue out, so I am excluding its results from the accumulates array C_final for now
- The idea is to break the initial problem size of (6000*6000) into (6000*6000)/20 sized chunks (if I am using 20 threads, for example)
- Then I want to send each thread's C array to the master thread and accumulate it into C_final
- I send the thread number before I send the data so I can place the received data in the right position to make the final array in order of each thread's data (C_final = [Thread 1's data, Thread 2's data, ...])

So finally, my issue is that even though I can see that the data I am sending and receiving is correct by verifying it before I send it and verifying it when I receive it, because the the array I am sending is of uint8_t and not long, when I check it after all the results are received, I end up getting parts of the array with garbage data while other parts have the correct result. I tried making both C_final and C_priv longs instead of 8-bit integers and verified that the results are correct after receiving everything, but not when I have them as 8-bit integer arrays.

Unfortunately, for this application I need to have the arrays doing the computations as 8-bit integers. Also, I am going to be including the time it takes to accumulate all of the results from the threads into the final C_final array so I am trying to make sure the accumulation doesn't take too much time (so I don't want do something like copying the results of C_final into a long array and then send that new array).

Is there any way to alleviate this problem without just changing my C_priv arrays and C_final array into longs instead of 8-bit integers? Also, I looked into the source code of the message passing, and the functions look this:

```
// Receive a packet of words from UDN demux 1.
//
// @param buf A long-aligned buffer
// @param words The size of the buffer (in longs)
//
static __inline void
tmc_udn1_receive_buffer(void* buf, unsigned long words)
{
  unsigned long i;
  unsigned long* ptr = (unsigned long*)buf;
  for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
    ptr[i] = udn1_receive();
}

...

// Send a packet of words on the UDN
//
// @param dest The destination (with no length)
// @param tag The tag (e.g. UDN0_DEMUX_TAG)
// @param buf A long-aligned buffer
// @param words The size of the buffer (in longs). This function can
// send a maximum of 126 longs
//
static __inline void
tmc_udn_send_buffer(DynamicHeader dest, unsigned long tag,
                    const void* buf, unsigned long words)
{
  unsigned long i;
  const unsigned long* ptr = (const unsigned long*)buf;
  __tmc_udn_send_header_with_size_and_tag(dest, words, tag);
  for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
    udn_send(ptr[i]);
}
```

Edit:

For some additional clarity, this is the proper output I am expecting if I were to read the the indexes of C_final after accumulation. These are read at the first index of where each thread placed it's data (I was using 30 threads here but the idea is the same. Also the last one is -1 since I am omitting the master's thread results for now and just placing all the other thread's data in C_final starting at 0):

```
C_final[0] = 99
C_final[1875000] = 98
C_final[3750000] = 97
C_final[5625000] = 96
C_final[7500000] = 95
C_final[9375000] = 94
C_final[11250000] = 93
C_final[13125000] = 92
C_final[15000000] = 91
C_final[16875000] = 90
C_final[18750000] = 89
C_final[20625000] = 88
C_final[22500000] = 87
C_final[24375000] = 86
C_final[26250000] = 85
C_final[28125000] = 84
C_final[30000000] = 83
C_final[31875000] = 82
C_final[33750000] = 81
C_final[35625000] = 80
C_final[37500000] = 79
C_final[39375000] = 78
C_final[41250000] = 77
C_final[43125000] = 76
C_final[45000000] = 75
C_final[46875000] = 74
C_final[48750000] = 73
C_final[50625000] = 72
C_final[52500000] = 71
C_final[54375000] = -1
```

However, this is the result I am getting:

```
C_final[0] = 99
C_final[1875000] = -16
C_final[3750000] = 97
C_final[5625000] = 96
C_final[7500000] = 95
C_final[9375000] = -16
C_final[11250000] = -16
C_final[13125000] = 92
C_final[15000000] = -16
C_final[16875000] = 90
C_final[18750000] = -16
C_final[20625000] = 88
C_final[22500000] = -16
C_final[24375000] = -16
C_final[26250000] = 85
C_final[28125000] = -16
C_final[30000000] = -16
C_final[31875000] = 82
C_final[33750000] = -16
C_final[35625000] = -16
C_final[37500000] = -16
C_final[39375000] = 78
C_final[41250000] = -16
C_final[43125000] = 76
C_final[45000000] = -16
C_final[46875000] = -16
C_final[48750000] = 73
C_final[50625000] = 72
C_final[52500000] = -16
C_final[54375000] = -16
```

As for which results are accurate and which results are not, that changes every time I run it. It is not always the same indexes that have the correct results. The incorrect numbers that can be seen also are not consistent.

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings enabled, I believe this is either pointer alignment error, or strict aliasing violation

Comment: One possible fix would be to `memcpy` each long before sending.

Comment: I compiled with -Wall and didn't receive any warnings pertaining to it. I recently noticed that the results will get messed up if a chunk of results are received from a thread and they are placed in C_priv in a position that comes before another chunk of results that were already receivied. 

For example, if I received thread 3's results, they will be fine until thread 2's results come in and get placed in the indexes before it. I managed to make sure the threads send the results in thread order and now my results are accurate.